# How can i setting up HWIOAuthBundle with Symfony4?

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, symfony4, hwioauthbundle

I try to make a web application in symfony4. I want to make login/register system with HWIOAuthBundle, but I can't find a good setting up guide just for Symfony3. Anybody can help me?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think original docs are OK: https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-setting_up_the_bundle.md

Basically, bundles' configurations in Symfony 4 are pretty similar to Symfony 3 so you can try to use original docs. BTW there're some notes about Symfony 4.1 in this docs, so I'm sure that they will help you.